# Errors with JQuery - But I don't know how to solve

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Files available at: www.maharrington.co.uk/click](http://www.maharrington.co.uk)
Building a website for our student radio station - this code works in Firefox, but doesn't work in Chrome for some reason.
I've read previous posts where they had similar errors and it was due to the JavaScript not being put at the top of the page - however, having moved all of the JavaScript into the header, I can't understand why there are still numerous errors with the page (as ran in Chrome Debugging console).

```
 <!-- the jScrollPane script -->
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>      
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.contentcarousel.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                    $('#ca-container').contentcarousel();
        </script>       
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var aImages = [ "images/banner/banner1.jpg" , "images/banner/banner2.jpg", "images/banner/banner3.jpg", "images/banner/banner4.jpg",];
            var oImage = null;
            var iIdx = 0;

    function play(){
    try{
            //look only once in DOM and cache it
            if(oImage===null){
            oImage = window.document.getElementById("imgHolder");
            }
            oImage.src = aImages[(++iIdx)%(aImages.length)];
        setTimeout('play()',10000);
        }catch(oEx){
        //some error handling here
        }
        }
        </script>       
</head>
    <body onload="play()">
<section id="content">
    <section id="headerArea">
        <section id="mainHeader">
            <section id="leftHeader">
                <a href="index.php"> <img src="images/clicklogowb.png" height="200px" width="330"> </a>
            </section>          
            <section id="rightHeader">
                <section id="rightTop">
                    <img src="images/header.png">
                </section>
        </section>
    <style type="text/css"> #mainContent {margin-top:-16%;} </style>
<link href="css/presenters.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- the jScrollPane script -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.contentcarousel.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#ca-container').contentcarousel();
        </script>
<section id="mainContent">
        <section id="blocks">
                <section id="topBlocks">

  <br>
    <h5>Presenters</h5>
            <div id="ca-container" class="ca-container">
                <div class="ca-wrapper">
                    <div class="ca-item ca-item-1">
                        <div class="ca-item-main">
                            <div class="ca-icon"></div>
                            <h3>Priscilla</h3>
                            <h4>
                                <span class="ca-quote">&ldquo;</span>
                                <span>The greatness of a nation and its moral progress can be judged by the way in which its animals are treated.</span>
                            </h4>
                                <a href="#" class="ca-more">more...</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ca-content-wrapper">
                            <div class="ca-content">

                                <a href="#" class="ca-close">close</a>
                                <div class="ca-content-text">
                                    <p>I am so happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my talents. I should be incapable of drawing a single stroke at the present moment; and yet I feel that I never was a greater artist than now.</p>
                                    <p>When, while the lovely valley teems with vapour around me, and the meridian sun strikes the upper surface of the impenetrable foliage of my trees, and but a few stray gleams steal into the inner sanctuary, I throw myself down among the tall grass by the trickling stream;</p>
                                    <p>She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way.</p>
                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ca-item ca-item-2">
                        <div class="ca-item-main">
                            <div class="ca-icon"></div>
                            <h3>Lucy</h3>
                            <h4>
                                <span class="ca-quote">&ldquo;</span>
                                <span>I hold that the more helpless a creature, the more entitled it is to protection by man from the cruelty of man.</span>
                            </h4>
                                <a href="#" class="ca-more">more...</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ca-content-wrapper">
                            <div class="ca-content">
                                                            <a href="#" class="ca-close">close</a>
                                <div class="ca-content-text">
                                    <p>I am so happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my talents. I should be incapable of drawing a single stroke at the present moment; and yet I feel that I never was a greater artist than now.</p>
                                    <p>When, while the lovely valley teems with vapour around me, and the meridian sun strikes the upper surface of the impenetrable foliage of my trees, and but a few stray gleams steal into the inner sanctuary, I throw myself down among the tall grass by the trickling stream;</p>
                                    <p>She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way.</p>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ca-item ca-item-3">
                        <div class="ca-item-main">
                            <div class="ca-icon"></div>
                            <h3>Nat</h3>
                            <h4>
                                <span class="ca-quote">&ldquo;</span>
                                <span>I feel that spiritual progress does demand at some stage that we should cease to kill our fellow creatures for the satisfaction of our bodily wants.</span>
                            </h4>
                                <a href="#" class="ca-more">more...</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ca-content-wrapper">
                            <div class="ca-content">
                                                            <a href="#" class="ca-close">close</a>
                                <div class="ca-content-text">
                                    <p>I am so happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my talents. I should be incapable of drawing a single stroke at the present moment; and yet I feel that I never was a greater artist than now.</p>
                                    <p>When, while the lovely valley teems with vapour around me, and the meridian sun strikes the upper surface of the impenetrable foliage of my trees, and but a few stray gleams steal into the inner sanctuary, I throw myself down among the tall grass by the trickling stream;</p>
                                    <p>She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way.</p>
                                </div>
                                                    </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ca-item ca-item-4">
                        <div class="ca-item-main">
                            <div class="ca-icon"></div>
                            <h3>Katya</h3>
                            <h4>
                                <span class="ca-quote">&ldquo;</span>
                                <span>A man is but the product of his thoughts what he thinks, he becomes.</span>
                            </h4>
                                <a href="#" class="ca-more">more...</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ca-content-wrapper">
                            <div class="ca-content">
                                                            <a href="#" class="ca-close">close</a>
                                <div class="ca-content-text">
                                    <p>I am so happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my talents. I should be incapable of drawing a single stroke at the present moment; and yet I feel that I never was a greater artist than now.</p>
                                    <p>When, while the lovely valley teems with vapour around me, and the meridian sun strikes the upper surface of the impenetrable foliage of my trees, and but a few stray gleams steal into the inner sanctuary, I throw myself down among the tall grass by the trickling stream;</p>
                                    <p>She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way.</p>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ca-item ca-item-5">
                        <div class="ca-item-main">
                            <div class="ca-icon"></div>
                            <h3>Rebecca</h3>
                            <h4>
                                <span class="ca-quote">&ldquo;</span>
                                <span>A weak man is just by accident. A strong but non-violent man is unjust by accident.</span>
                            </h4>
                                <a href="#" class="ca-more">more...</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ca-content-wrapper">
                            <div class="ca-content">
                                                                <a href="#" class="ca-close">close</a>
                                <div class="ca-content-text">
                                    <p>I am so happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my talents. I should be incapable of drawing a single stroke at the present moment; and yet I feel that I never was a greater artist than now.</p>
                                    <p>When, while the lovely valley teems with vapour around me, and the meridian sun strikes the upper surface of the impenetrable foliage of my trees, and but a few stray gleams steal into the inner sanctuary, I throw myself down among the tall grass by the trickling stream;</p>
                                    <p>She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way.</p>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ca-item ca-item-6">
                        <div class="ca-item-main">
                            <div class="ca-icon"></div>
                            <h3>Dan</h3>
                            <h4>
                                <span class="ca-quote">&ldquo;</span>
                                <span>An error does not become truth by reason of multiplied propagation, nor does truth become error because nobody sees it.</span>
                            </h4>
                                <a href="#" class="ca-more">more...</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ca-content-wrapper">
                            <div class="ca-content">

                                <a href="#" class="ca-close">close</a>
                                <div class="ca-content-text">
                                    <p>I am so happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my talents. I should be incapable of drawing a single stroke at the present moment; and yet I feel that I never was a greater artist than now.</p>
                                    <p>When, while the lovely valley teems with vapour around me, and the meridian sun strikes the upper surface of the impenetrable foliage of my trees, and but a few stray gleams steal into the inner sanctuary, I throw myself down among the tall grass by the trickling stream;</p>
                                    <p>She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way.</p>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ca-item ca-item-7">
                        <div class="ca-item-main">
                            <div class="ca-icon"></div>
                            <h3>Rebecca</h3>
                            <h4>
                                <span class="ca-quote">&ldquo;</span>
                                <span>A small body of determined spirits fired by an unquenchable faith in their mission can alter the course of history.</span>
                            </h4>
                                <a href="#" class="ca-more">more...</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ca-content-wrapper">
                            <div class="ca-content">

                                <a href="#" class="ca-close">close</a>
                                <div class="ca-content-text">
                                    <p>I am so happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my talents. I should be incapable of drawing a single stroke at the present moment; and yet I feel that I never was a greater artist than now.</p>
                                    <p>When, while the lovely valley teems with vapour around me, and the meridian sun strikes the upper surface of the impenetrable foliage of my trees, and but a few stray gleams steal into the inner sanctuary, I throw myself down among the tall grass by the trickling stream;</p>
                                    <p>She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way.</p>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ca-item ca-item-8">
                        <div class="ca-item-main">
                            <div class="ca-icon"></div>
                            <h3>Diarmuid</h3>
                            <h4>
                                <span class="ca-quote">&ldquo;</span>
                                <span>A nation's culture resides in the hearts and in the soul of its people.</span>
                            </h4>
                                <a href="#" class="ca-more">more...</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ca-content-wrapper">
                            <div class="ca-content">
                                                            <a href="#" class="ca-close">close</a>
                                <div class="ca-content-text">
                                    <p>I am so happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my talents. I should be incapable of drawing a single stroke at the present moment; and yet I feel that I never was a greater artist than now.</p>
                                    <p>When, while the lovely valley teems with vapour around me, and the meridian sun strikes the upper surface of the impenetrable foliage of my trees, and but a few stray gleams steal into the inner sanctuary, I throw myself down among the tall grass by the trickling stream;</p>
                                    <p>She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way.</p>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ca-item ca-item-9">
                        <div class="ca-item-main">
                            <div class="ca-icon"></div>
                            <h3>Sian</h3>
                            <h4>
                                <span class="ca-quote">&ldquo;</span>
                                <span>A nation's culture resides in the hearts and in the soul of its people.</span>
                            </h4>
                                <a href="#" class="ca-more">more...</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ca-content-wrapper">
                            <div class="ca-content">
                                                            <a href="#" class="ca-close">close</a>
                                <div class="ca-content-text">
                                    <p>I am so happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my talents. I should be incapable of drawing a single stroke at the present moment; and yet I feel that I never was a greater artist than now.</p>
                                    <p>When, while the lovely valley teems with vapour around me, and the meridian sun strikes the upper surface of the impenetrable foliage of my trees, and but a few stray gleams steal into the inner sanctuary, I throw myself down among the tall grass by the trickling stream;</p>
                                    <p>She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way.</p>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ca-item ca-item-10">
                        <div class="ca-item-main">
                            <div class="ca-icon"></div>
                            <h3>Etienne</h3>
                            <h4>
                                <span class="ca-quote">&ldquo;</span>
                                <span>A nation's culture resides in the hearts and in the soul of its people.</span>
                            </h4>
                                <a href="#" class="ca-more">more...</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ca-content-wrapper">
                            <div class="ca-content">
                                                            <a href="#" class="ca-close">close</a>
                                <div class="ca-content-text">
                                    <p>I am so happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my talents. I should be incapable of drawing a single stroke at the present moment; and yet I feel that I never was a greater artist than now.</p>
                                    <p>When, while the lovely valley teems with vapour around me, and the meridian sun strikes the upper surface of the impenetrable foliage of my trees, and but a few stray gleams steal into the inner sanctuary, I throw myself down among the tall grass by the trickling stream;</p>
                                    <p>She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way.</p>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ca-item ca-item-11">
                        <div class="ca-item-main">
                            <div class="ca-icon"></div>
                            <h3>Matthew</h3>
                            <h4>
                                <span class="ca-quote">&ldquo;</span>
                                <span>A nation's culture resides in the hearts and in the soul of its people.</span>
                            </h4>
                                <a href="#" class="ca-more">more...</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ca-content-wrapper">
                            <div class="ca-content">
                                                            <a href="#" class="ca-close">close</a>
                                <div class="ca-content-text">
                                    <p>I am so happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my talents. I should be incapable of drawing a single stroke at the present moment; and yet I feel that I never was a greater artist than now.</p>
                                    <p>When, while the lovely valley teems with vapour around me, and the meridian sun strikes the upper surface of the impenetrable foliage of my trees, and but a few stray gleams steal into the inner sanctuary, I throw myself down among the tall grass by the trickling stream;</p>
                                    <p>She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way.</p>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ca-item ca-item-12">
                        <div class="ca-item-main">
                            <div class="ca-icon"></div>
                            <h3>Alex</h3>
                            <h4>
                                <span class="ca-quote">&ldquo;</span>
                                <span>A nation's culture resides in the hearts and in the soul of its people.</span>
                            </h4>
                                <a href="#" class="ca-more">more...</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ca-content-wrapper">
                            <div class="ca-content">
                                                            <a href="#" class="ca-close">close</a>
                                <div class="ca-content-text">
                                    <p>I am so happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my talents. I should be incapable of drawing a single stroke at the present moment; and yet I feel that I never was a greater artist than now.</p>
                                    <p>When, while the lovely valley teems with vapour around me, and the meridian sun strikes the upper surface of the impenetrable foliage of my trees, and but a few stray gleams steal into the inner sanctuary, I throw myself down among the tall grass by the trickling stream;</p>
                                    <p>She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way.</p>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ca-item ca-item-13">
                        <div class="ca-item-main">
                            <div class="ca-icon"></div>
                            <h3>Jamie</h3>
                            <h4>
                                <span class="ca-quote">&ldquo;</span>
                                <span>A nation's culture resides in the hearts and in the soul of its people.</span>
                            </h4>
                                <a href="#" class="ca-more">more...</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ca-content-wrapper">
                            <div class="ca-content">
                                                            <a href="#" class="ca-close">close</a>
                                <div class="ca-content-text">
                                    <p>I am so happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my talents. I should be incapable of drawing a single stroke at the present moment; and yet I feel that I never was a greater artist than now.</p>
                                    <p>When, while the lovely valley teems with vapour around me, and the meridian sun strikes the upper surface of the impenetrable foliage of my trees, and but a few stray gleams steal into the inner sanctuary, I throw myself down among the tall grass by the trickling stream;</p>
                                    <p>She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way.</p>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ca-item ca-item-14">
                        <div class="ca-item-main">
                            <div class="ca-icon"></div>
                            <h3>Matt</h3>
                            <h4>
                                <span class="ca-quote">&ldquo;</span>
                                <span>A nation's culture resides in the hearts and in the soul of its people.</span>
                            </h4>
                                <a href="#" class="ca-more">more...</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ca-content-wrapper">
                            <div class="ca-content">
                                                            <a href="#" class="ca-close">close</a>
                                <div class="ca-content-text">
                                    <p>I am so happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my talents. I should be incapable of drawing a single stroke at the present moment; and yet I feel that I never was a greater artist than now.</p>
                                    <p>When, while the lovely valley teems with vapour around me, and the meridian sun strikes the upper surface of the impenetrable foliage of my trees, and but a few stray gleams steal into the inner sanctuary, I throw myself down among the tall grass by the trickling stream;</p>
                                    <p>She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way.</p>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ca-item ca-item-15">
                        <div class="ca-item-main">
                            <div class="ca-icon"></div>
                            <h3>Sam</h3>
                            <h4>
                                <span class="ca-quote">&ldquo;</span>
                                <span>A nation's culture resides in the hearts and in the soul of its people.</span>
                            </h4>
                                <a href="#" class="ca-more">more...</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ca-content-wrapper">
                            <div class="ca-content">
                                                            <a href="#" class="ca-close">close</a>
                                <div class="ca-content-text">
                                    <p>I am so happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my talents. I should be incapable of drawing a single stroke at the present moment; and yet I feel that I never was a greater artist than now.</p>
                                    <p>When, while the lovely valley teems with vapour around me, and the meridian sun strikes the upper surface of the impenetrable foliage of my trees, and but a few stray gleams steal into the inner sanctuary, I throw myself down among the tall grass by the trickling stream;</p>
                                    <p>She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way.</p>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ca-item ca-item-16">
                        <div class="ca-item-main">
                            <div class="ca-icon"></div>
                            <h3>Stefan</h3>
                            <h4>
                                <span class="ca-quote">&ldquo;</span>
                                <span>A nation's culture resides in the hearts and in the soul of its people.</span>
                            </h4>
                                <a href="#" class="ca-more">more...</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ca-content-wrapper">
                            <div class="ca-content">
                                                            <a href="#" class="ca-close">close</a>
                                <div class="ca-content-text">
                                    <p>I am so happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my talents. I should be incapable of drawing a single stroke at the present moment; and yet I feel that I never was a greater artist than now.</p>
                                    <p>When, while the lovely valley teems with vapour around me, and the meridian sun strikes the upper surface of the impenetrable foliage of my trees, and but a few stray gleams steal into the inner sanctuary, I throw myself down among the tall grass by the trickling stream;</p>
                                    <p>She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way.</p>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ca-item ca-item-17">
                        <div class="ca-item-main">
                            <div class="ca-icon"></div>
                            <h3>George</h3>
                            <h4>
                                <span class="ca-quote">&ldquo;</span>
                                <span>A nation's culture resides in the hearts and in the soul of its people.</span>
                            </h4>
                                <a href="#" class="ca-more">more...</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ca-content-wrapper">
                            <div class="ca-content">
                                                            <a href="#" class="ca-close">close</a>
                                <div class="ca-content-text">
                                    <p>I am so happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my talents. I should be incapable of drawing a single stroke at the present moment; and yet I feel that I never was a greater artist than now.</p>
                                    <p>When, while the lovely valley teems with vapour around me, and the meridian sun strikes the upper surface of the impenetrable foliage of my trees, and but a few stray gleams steal into the inner sanctuary, I throw myself down among the tall grass by the trickling stream;</p>
                                    <p>She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way.</p>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I can provide the code files by email/other means if it is easier for you to view?

---

Here are the errors:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.mousewheel.js:78
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.contentcarousel.js:257
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined shows.php:34
[blocked] The page at scm-intranet.tees.ac.uk/users/l1009357/click_new/shows.php ran insecure content from ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.easing.1.3.js:39
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.mousewheel.js:78
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.contentcarousel.js:257
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined shows.php:267
```

Comment: Is the line referencing jQuery outside the code shown here, or is it possible you forgot to include it?

Comment: What exactly is broken?

Comment: What does the errors say?

Comment: @AllanKimmerJensen the errors were (part 1):
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.mousewheel.js:78
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.contentcarousel.js:257
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined shows.php:34
[blocked] The page at https://scm-intranet.tees.ac.uk/users/l1009357/click_new/shows.php ran insecure content from http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js.
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.easing.1.3.js:39
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.mousewheel.js:78

Comment: Make sure that you have referenced jQuery before any other scripts.. Have you even included jquery.js ?

Comment: @AllanKimmerJensen Part 2:
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.contentcarousel.js:257
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined shows.php:267

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned the problem is in your jQuery code. The only jQuery call I see is this one:

```
$('#ca-container').contentcarousel();
```

If this is not working properly, there's a good chance it's because you need to wait to execute that until the document is loaded:

```
$(document).on('ready', function() {
    $('#ca-container').contentcarousel();
});
```

Otherwise the `ca-container` element does not exist when the jQuery code is executed.

---

***UPDATE:***

You are also forgetting to include the jQuery library in the `<head>`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, maybe it's work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#ca-container').contentcarousel();
});
```

call the `contentcarousel()` after window loaded compeletly

you need also include jquery before another js libraries :

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

move your carousel jQuery code from body to the head element and call it on the document.ready event, also include a reference to the jQuery library itself:

```
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
 <style type="text/css"> #mainContent {margin-top:-16%;} </style>
<link href="css/presenters.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- the jScrollPane script -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.contentcarousel.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                        $('#ca-container').contentcarousel();
                    });
        </script>       
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var aImages = [ "images/banner/banner1.jpg" , "images/banner/banner2.jpg", "images/banner/banner3.jpg", "images/banner/banner4.jpg",];
            var oImage = null;
            var iIdx = 0;

    function play(){
    try{
            //look only once in DOM and cache it
            if(oImage===null){
            oImage = window.document.getElementById("imgHolder");
            }
            oImage.src = aImages[(++iIdx)%(aImages.length)];
        setTimeout('play()',10000);
        }catch(oEx){
        //some error handling here
        }
        }
        </script>   



</head>
    <body onload="play()">
<section id="content">
    <section id="headerArea">
        <section id="mainHeader">
            <section id="leftHeader">
                <a href="index.php"> <img src="images/clicklogowb.png" height="200px" width="330"> </a>
            </section>          
            <section id="rightHeader">
                <section id="rightTop">
                    <img src="images/header.png">
                </section>
        </section>

<section id="mainContent">
        <section id="blocks">
                <section id="topBlocks">

  <br>
    <h5>Presenters</h5>
            <div id="ca-container" class="ca-container">
                <div class="ca-wrapper">
                    <div class="ca-item ca-item-1">
                        <div class="ca-item-main">
                            <div class="ca-icon"></div>
                            <h3>Priscilla</h3>
                            <h4>
                                <span class="ca-quote">&ldquo;</span>
                                <span>The greatness of a nation and its moral progress can be judged by the way in which its animals are treated.</span>
                            </h4>
                                <a href="#" class="ca-more">more...</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ca-content-wrapper">
                            <div class="ca-content">

                                <a href="#" class="ca-close">close</a>
                                <div class="ca-content-text">
                                    <p>I am so happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my talents. I should be incapable of drawing a single stroke at the present moment; and yet I feel that I never was a greater artist than now.</p>
                                    <p>When, while the lovely valley teems with vapour around me, and the meridian sun strikes the upper surface of the impenetrable foliage of my trees, and but a few stray gleams steal into the inner sanctuary, I throw myself down among the tall grass by the trickling stream;</p>
                                    <p>She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way.</p>
                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ca-item ca-item-2">
                        <div class="ca-item-main">
                            <div class="ca-icon"></div>
                            <h3>Lucy</h3>
                            <h4>
                                <span class="ca-quote">&ldquo;</span>
                                <span>I hold that the more helpless a creature, the more entitled it is to protection by man from the cruelty of man.</span>
                            </h4>
                                <a href="#" class="ca-more">more...</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ca-content-wrapper">
                            <div class="ca-content">
                                                            <a href="#" class="ca-close">close</a>
                                <div class="ca-content-text">
                                    <p>I am so happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my talents. I should be incapable of drawing a single stroke at the present moment; and yet I feel that I never was a greater artist than now.</p>
                                    <p>When, while the lovely valley teems with vapour around me, and the meridian sun strikes the upper surface of the impenetrable foliage of my trees, and but a few stray gleams steal into the inner sanctuary, I throw myself down among the tall grass by the trickling stream;</p>
                                    <p>She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way.</p>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ca-item ca-item-3">
                        <div class="ca-item-main">
                            <div class="ca-icon"></div>
                            <h3>Nat</h3>
                            <h4>
                                <span class="ca-quote">&ldquo;</span>
                                <span>I feel that spiritual progress does demand at some stage that we should cease to kill our fellow creatures for the satisfaction of our bodily wants.</span>
                            </h4>
                                <a href="#" class="ca-more">more...</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ca-content-wrapper">
                            <div class="ca-content">
                                                            <a href="#" class="ca-close">close</a>
                                <div class="ca-content-text">
                                    <p>I am so happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my talents. I should be incapable of drawing a single stroke at the present moment; and yet I feel that I never was a greater artist than now.</p>
                                    <p>When, while the lovely valley teems with vapour around me, and the meridian sun strikes the upper surface of the impenetrable foliage of my trees, and but a few stray gleams steal into the inner sanctuary, I throw myself down among the tall grass by the trickling stream;</p>
                                    <p>She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way.</p>
                                </div>
                                                    </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ca-item ca-item-4">
                        <div class="ca-item-main">
                            <div class="ca-icon"></div>
                            <h3>Katya</h3>
                            <h4>
                                <span class="ca-quote">&ldquo;</span>
                                <span>A man is but the product of his thoughts what he thinks, he becomes.</span>
                            </h4>
                                <a href="#" class="ca-more">more...</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ca-content-wrapper">
                            <div class="ca-content">
                                                            <a href="#" class="ca-close">close</a>
                                <div class="ca-content-text">
                                    <p>I am so happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my talents. I should be incapable of drawing a single stroke at the present moment; and yet I feel that I never was a greater artist than now.</p>
                                    <p>When, while the lovely valley teems with vapour around me, and the meridian sun strikes the upper surface of the impenetrable foliage of my trees, and but a few stray gleams steal into the inner sanctuary, I throw myself down among the tall grass by the trickling stream;</p>
                                    <p>She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way.</p>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ca-item ca-item-5">
                        <div class="ca-item-main">
                            <div class="ca-icon"></div>
                            <h3>Rebecca</h3>
                            <h4>
                                <span class="ca-quote">&ldquo;</span>
                                <span>A weak man is just by accident. A strong but non-violent man is unjust by accident.</span>
                            </h4>
                                <a href="#" class="ca-more">more...</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ca-content-wrapper">
                            <div class="ca-content">
                                                                <a href="#" class="ca-close">close</a>
                                <div class="ca-content-text">
                                    <p>I am so happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my talents. I should be incapable of drawing a single stroke at the present moment; and yet I feel that I never was a greater artist than now.</p>
                                    <p>When, while the lovely valley teems with vapour around me, and the meridian sun strikes the upper surface of the impenetrable foliage of my trees, and but a few stray gleams steal into the inner sanctuary, I throw myself down among the tall grass by the trickling stream;</p>
                                    <p>She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way.</p>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ca-item ca-item-6">
                        <div class="ca-item-main">
                            <div class="ca-icon"></div>
                            <h3>Dan</h3>
                            <h4>
                                <span class="ca-quote">&ldquo;</span>
                                <span>An error does not become truth by reason of multiplied propagation, nor does truth become error because nobody sees it.</span>
                            </h4>
                                <a href="#" class="ca-more">more...</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ca-content-wrapper">
                            <div class="ca-content">

                                <a href="#" class="ca-close">close</a>
                                <div class="ca-content-text">
                                    <p>I am so happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my talents. I should be incapable of drawing a single stroke at the present moment; and yet I feel that I never was a greater artist than now.</p>
                   ---------------- TRUNCATED
```

Comment: This doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: This comment doesn't help me in helping you. What error did you get?

Answer (score 0):

What error are you getting?

Have you forgotten to include Jquery in snippet?

You've included following scripts in your page twice (in head and body).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>      
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.contentcarousel.js"></script>
```

It might be the problem and make sure you add plugin code in document.ready.

Answer (score 0):

you are getting error `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`

Make sure that you have referenced jQuery before any other scripts.. Have you even included jquery.js ?

Try adding this to the head section before you include any other script

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`